# php session every 24 hours to be cleaned

Tags: php

I want one session variable to be cleaned every 24 hours .I don't want to kill or unset all the sessions just one session to be unset every 24 hours a day.

Comment: one session where? on the server? on the client? on the moon?

Comment: one session variable or one session? decide :)

Comment: what stops a client shutting their computer down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the session is 1st created on the client just give it a date:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['date'])
    $_SESSION['date'] = date('m_d_y');
```

Then whenever the page changes check that date:

```
if($_SESSION['date'] == date('m_d_y')){
   //still today
}
else {
   //destroy session
}
```

Or you could do it with timestamp and check based on the number of hours:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['creationTime'])
    $_SESSION['creationTime'] = time();

if (time() - $_SESSION['creationTime'] <= 60*60*24 ){
   //still today
}
else {
   //destroy session
}
```

Comment: every 24 hours != when the date changed

Comment: @Dvir, yes, but it is better than calculating # of seconds in the day on every page

Comment: @Neal: no actually is not, you dont must calculating this, this is base value of time, now you calculating date from this using `date` function then your solution is inefficient.

Comment: @Neal, you don't have to do that. Write the unix timestamp the session was created on to $_SESSION['creationTime'] and then just check if time() - $_SESSION['creationTime'] is more than 60*60*24 - if it is, unset the desired variable/whole session.

Comment: @Dvir yes yes yes, i know that. this is just a simplified way. i have the timstamp idea also at the end of the answer

Comment: I notice it now, you should promote that solution instead of the date one :)

Comment: @Dvir, i now added it as an actual example

Comment: @Neal, you just have to fix the <= into >= and the $_SESSION['date'] into $_SESSION['creationTime'] or the other way around, and it's perfect. Thanks for adding that into your answer as well!

Comment: @Dvir, what i have there is correct, if `<= 24 hours` then it is still today :-P

Comment: oh, you're right, I missed the `// still today` and thought it was the cleaning block. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

try to set Cookie expired time into now() + 24 hours...

Comment: actually session is a cookie, and in php.ini can set expire time of it.

Comment: It about client side if I'm not mistaken, and session is connected to the client by the cookie in general...

Answer (score 1):

When you creating session, write to it timestamp. Then you are using seesion check the actually timestamp and of creating session, then if difference is grather than 86400, then drop session and create new one.

This solution prevent users from using sessions older than 24hours. You can apply other comparing algorithm to eg. prevent users from using session before 1AM of current day. Then will be work exaclly same when you will want erase session every 24hours in 1AM every day.

Answer (score 0):

When create session (maybe when user login), declare session timeout:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION["timeout"] = time()+ (60*60*24);
```

Create backend function / page where jquery can call every 10 seconds / 5 seconds up to you (I save it  as get_session.php):

```
session_start(); 
$session_life = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
$inactive = 0; 

if($session_life > $inactive){  
   session_destroy(); 
   echo 'Destroyed';
}
```

The jquery script run every 5 second (recommended at master page / template header / footer of the page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setInterval(function(){
  sessionHeartBeat();
}, 5000);
function sessionHeartBeat(){
$.ajax({
  url: 'get_session.php',
  success: function(response){
  console.log(response);
  }
});
}
</script>
```